# strtok_r causing "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, string, variable-assignment, strtok

I'm attempting to tokenize a String in C and save the tokens into multiple variables using strtok_r. As far as I can tell, I'm using it exactly as documented:

```
char *saveptr;

char *ticketuser = strtok_r(request, ":", &saveptr);
char *ticketservice = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
char *ticketkey = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
//And so on...
```

Where 'request' is a String of colon-delimited tokens. When I try to compile, I get "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" on each line where I assign one of the Strings. Since strtok_r is supposed to return a char*, I can't see what the issue is.

EDIT: Here's ALL my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *add( char *request ) {

  char *name = "add";
  char *secret = "secret1";
  char *failcode = "0:add:0";
  char returncode[80];
  char *saveptr;

  char *username = strtok_r(request, ":", &saveptr);
  char *servicename = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
  int parameter1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr));
  int parameter2 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr));
  int ticketlead1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr));
  char *ticketuser = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
  char *ticketservice = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);
  char *ticketkey = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);

  //Catch any issues with the request
  if (strcmp(username,ticketuser) != 0){
    printf("username did not match ticket username\n");
    return failcode;
  }//if
  else if (strcmp(servicename,ticketservice) != 0){
    printf("service name did not match ticket service name\n");
    return failcode;
  }//else if
  else if (strcmp(secret,ticketkey) != 0){
    printf("secret key did not match ticket secret key\n");
    return failcode;
  }//else if

  //request was good, return value
  else{
    int val = parameter1 + parameter2;
    sprintf(returncode, "1:add:%d", val);
    return returncode;
  }//else

}//add


int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

  char *returned;
  char *req = "user:serv:5:8:1:user:serv:secret1";
  returned  = add(req);

  printf(returned);
  printf("\n");

  return 1;

}//main
```

Comment: That should be fine (http://ideone.com/Dty4x7); you'll need to post a complete test-case.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string.h>`.  But you should also be compiling with `-Wall -Werror`, as that would have told you about it...

Comment: *Slaps forehead* Thank you. I had a feeling it would be something like this. I am compiling with -Wall, but I think I'll have to add -Werror now.

Comment: `-Werror` simply causes all warnings to be turned into errors, preventing compilation from succeeding.  It's pretty useful!  I'd also recommend `-Wextra`.

Comment: I see, thanks. What does -Wextra do?

Comment: It enables a bunch of useful warnings that aren't covered by `-Wall`.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options for the full list of flags that you can use.

Comment: All right, thanks again. Hm... now the line 
char *username = strtok_r(request, ":", &saveptr);
is causing a segfault (so, presumably, all of them will). Problems, problems...

Comment: Post the answer as an answer so the question doesn't show up with 0 answers even though it's been figured out.  If no one does in an hour I will.

Comment: @JMcMinn if it's segfaulting still, request is probably not a valid pointer or it's not null terminated.

Comment: `char returncode[80]` is local variable. and `char *req = "user:serv:5:8:1:user:serv:secret1";` read only in most cases.

Comment: Right, I see... C is such a pain for someone who was never taught it properly XP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer was found in comments: I was missing `#include <string.h>` at the top of the file.

EDIT: I should add that there were other issues besides the one mentioned above. Firstly, `saveptr` should be initialized to null. Secondly, as BLUEPIXY pointed out, `returncode[]` was a local variable. Replaced its definition with `char *returncode = malloc ( . . . );`

Answer (score 0):

This can be removed by using "string.h" header file in C

Comment: Do you mean `#include <string.h>` as described in [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17015777/622391)?